# Laravel Error undefined variable when trying to populate DropDown from database

Tags: php, laravel

Iam new with Laravel trying to add user type in register blade page as drop down from my database but it give me every time the same error
 Undefined variable: uTypes (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/creativeapp/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php)

The Route code web.php:

```
Route::get('/auth/register', 'UsersController@index');
```

The controller code UsersController.php:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UsersController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $uTypes = DB::table('userstype')->pluck("type_name", "id");
        return view('auth.register', ['uTypes' => $uTypes]);
    }
}
```

The view code register.blade.php:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="usertype" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('User Type') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">


                                <select name="userType" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">--Select Type--</option>
                                    @foreach ($uTypes as $ut => $value)
                                    <option value="{{ $ut }}"> {{ $value }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[Route web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JViC.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Jw9.jpg)

[register.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wGXh.jpg)

[usercontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd7vo.jpg)

Comment: Did you use artisan auth ?

Comment: @ Saromase Yes i did

Comment: Your codes seem correct. Try to put fake values in `$uTypes` as `['uTypes' => ['Type 1' => 1, 'type2' => 2]]`. But this behavior is weird. Also try clearing cache and views with `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`.

Comment: Does this `DB::table('userstype')->pluck("type_name", "id")` actually returns something ?

Comment: You must try to echo something in your controller index method to see if the codes have even run in there. This way you will know what to change.

Comment: @MohamadSalama Have you solve your problem ?

Comment: i tryed to make echo and it bring the data from database 

 but still the old error

Comment: iam using MAMP pro if it cause the problem ?

Comment: What about when you pass hard coded data like `['uTypes' => ['Type 1' => 1, 'type2' => 2]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to rewrite Route, use auth native route.

You need to overwrite the `getRegister` method into `RegisterController`.

app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

```
/**
 * Show the application registration form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getRegister()
{
    $uTypes = DB::table('userstype')->pluck("type_name", "id");
    return view('auth.register', ['uTypes' => $uTypes]);

}
```

And after that, dont forget to update validator, migration and create method

Comment: Can you show us, the result of `dd($uTypes)` before return view ?